# Method in Python for finding a row based on conditions between rows with a start or stop condition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I need to determine which calls are associated with a ticket search and add a value in a new column, tracking correlations.  The data is sorted chronologically.

My data pattern is as follows:

```
TIME,INDEX,TYPE,SPLIT,LOGIN,USERNAME,TICKETUD,ACCOUNTID
3/10/2019 14:53,1853,START,111,xxxx732,USER_1,,
3/10/2019 14:54,1848,START,111,xxxx738,USER_4,,
3/10/2019 14:55,1850,START,111,xxxx726,USER_2,,
3/10/2019 14:55,1846,STOP,333,xxxx744,USER_5,,
3/10/2019 14:56,1849,START,333,xxxx744,USER_5,,
3/10/2019 14:57,1855,START,333,xxxx738,USER_4,,
3/10/2019 14:57,0,SEARCH,,xxxx732,USER_1,xxxxx39,
3/10/2019 14:59,1852,START,333,xxxx726,USER_2,,
3/10/2019 15:00,1847,STOP,333,xxxx744,USER_5,,
3/10/2019 15:00,1848,STOP,111,xxxx738,USER_4,,
3/10/2019 15:03,1849,STOP,333,xxxx744,USER_5,,
3/10/2019 15:04,0,SEARCH,,xxxx732,USER_1,xxxxx39,
3/10/2019 15:05,1854,START,333,xxxx619,USER_3,,
3/10/2019 15:05,1850,STOP,111,xxxx726,USER_2,,
3/10/2019 15:07,1851,STOP,333,xxxx619,USER_3,,
3/10/2019 15:08,1852,STOP,333,xxxx726,USER_2,,
3/10/2019 15:09,1856,START,333,xxxx732,USER_1,,
3/10/2019 15:09,1858,START,333,xxxx619,USER_3,,
3/10/2019 15:09,1860,START,222,xxxx726,USER_2,,
3/10/2019 15:11,1853,STOP,111,xxxx732,USER_1,,
```

Column INDEX contains unique ID's for a given phone call.
Column TYPE contains the START and STOP value for the phone call and a SEARCH value indicating a ticket search.
The key for correlation is the LOGIN which tracks a user id.

At START, I need to find a correlating SEARCH before I reach a STOP and if a set contains a START SEARCH (maybe multiple searches) STOP pattern, I need to mark the set as connected, possibly counting sets like 1, 2, 3.

SET Example

```
TIME:3/10/2019 14:53 INDEX:1853 TYPE:START LOGIN:xxxx732
TIME:3/10/2019 14:57 INDEX:0 TYPE:SEARCH LOGIN:xxxx732
TIME:3/10/2019 15:04 INDEX:0 TYPE:SEARCH LOGIN:xxxx732
TIME:3/10/2019 15:11 INDEX:1853 TYPE:STOP LOGIN:xxxx732
```

My data is in a CSV file labeled combined.csv

I have been able to load the data and isolate a specifc row based on multiple conditions or assign true/false when a row meets a condition,

but I can not figure out how to trigger iteration on a set of conditions like TYPE: USER: and INDEX

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("combined.csv")
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# df['TEST'] = df['INDEX'].apply(lambda x: 'True' if x == 1 else 'False')
# print(df)


# test = df[(df.TYPE == "START") | (df.INDEX == 1)]
# print(test)
```

**UPDATE**

Would it make sense to delete this post at this point or submit the update as an answer?

I had some success reverting to csv versus pandas.
See below for current status.

My data pattern is as follows:

```
TIME,ID,TYPE,SPLIT,LOGIN,USERNAME,TICKETUD,ACCOUNTID
3/10/2019 14:53,1853,START,111,xxxx732,USER_1,,
3/10/2019 14:54,1848,START,111,xxxx738,USER_4,,
3/10/2019 14:55,1850,START,111,xxxx726,USER_2,,
3/10/2019 14:56,1849,START,333,xxxx744,USER_5,,
3/10/2019 14:57,1855,START,333,xxxx738,USER_4,,
3/10/2019 14:57,0,SEARCH,,xxxx732,USER_1,xxxxx39,
3/10/2019 14:58,0,SEARCH,,xxxx732,USER_1,,xxxxx21
3/10/2019 14:59,1852,START,333,xxxx726,USER_2,,
3/10/2019 15:00,1848,STOP,111,xxxx738,USER_4,,
3/10/2019 15:03,1849,STOP,333,xxxx744,USER_5,,
3/10/2019 15:04,0,SEARCH,,xxxx732,USER_1,xxxxx39,
3/10/2019 15:05,1854,START,333,xxxx619,USER_3,,
3/10/2019 15:05,1850,STOP,111,xxxx726,USER_2,,
3/10/2019 15:08,1852,STOP,333,xxxx726,USER_2,,
3/10/2019 15:11,1853,STOP,111,xxxx732,USER_1,,
3/10/2019 15:12,1855,STOP,333,xxxx738,USER_4,,
```

The data has been sorted chronologically
Column ID contains unique ID's for a given phone call.
Column TYPE contains the START and STOP value for a phone call and a SEARCH value indicating a ticket search. The key for correlation is the LOGIN which tracks a user id.

At START, I need to find a correlating SEARCH before I reach a STOP and if a set contains a START SEARCH (maybe multiple searches) STOP pattern, I need to mark the set as connected, possibly counting sets like 1, 2, 3.

SET Example

```
TIME:3/10/2019 14:53 ID:1853 TYPE:START LOGIN:xxxx732
TIME:3/10/2019 14:57 ID:0 TYPE:SEARCH LOGIN:xxxx732
TIME:3/10/2019 14:58,0,SEARCH,,xxxx732,USER_1,,xxxxx21
TIME:3/10/2019 15:04 ID:0 TYPE:SEARCH LOGIN:xxxx732
TIME:3/10/2019 15:11 ID:1853 TYPE:STOP LOGIN:xxxx732
```

Here is the code I have cobbled together now to find a SEARCH by LOGIN between a START and a STOP with the same ID.

```
import csv

call = 1853

def FINDSTART(call):
    with open('combined_3.csv') as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        for row in reader:
            time = str(row['TIME'])
            id = int(row['ID'])
            type = str(row['TYPE'])
            skill = str(row['DISPSPLIT'])
            login = str(row['ANSLOGIN'])
            if id == call and type == "START":
                arow = int(reader.line_num)
                print(arow,time,id,skill,login)
                return (reader.line_num), (time), (login)

def FINDSTOP(call):
    with open('combined_3.csv') as f2:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f2)
        for row in reader:
            time = str(row['TIME'])
            id = int(row['ID'])
            type = str(row['TYPE'])
            skill = str(row['DISPSPLIT'])
            login = str(row['ANSLOGIN'])
            if id == call and type == "STOP":
                brow = int(reader.line_num)
                print(brow,time,id,skill,login)
                return (reader.line_num), (time), (login)

def FINDSEARCH(aline,bline,aL):
        with open('combined_3.csv') as f3:
            reader = csv.DictReader(f3)
            for row in reader:
                time = str(row['TIME'])
                type = str(row['TYPE'])
                login = str(row['ANSLOGIN'])
                ticket = str(row['TICKETUD'])
                account = str(row['ACCOUNTID'])
                arow = int(aline)
                brow = int(bline)
                crow = int(reader.line_num)
                if type == "SEARCH" and aL == login and arow < crow < brow:
                    print(reader.line_num,time,login,ticket,account)
                    return (reader.line_num), (time), (login), (ticket), (account)


aLine, aT, aL = FINDSTART(call)

bLine, bT, bL = FINDSTOP(call)

cline, time, login, ticket, account = FINDSEARCH(aLine,bLine,aL)

print("Search" + ", " + time + ", " + login + ", " + ticket + ", " + account)
```

Here is the result from the code.

```
testfuct.py 
37928 3/10/2019 14:53 1853 708 1671732
37932 3/10/2019 15:11 1853 708 1671732
37929 3/10/2019 14:57 1671732 60954939
Search, 3/10/2019 14:57, 1671732, 60954939,
```

Outstanding Goals:
Count the difference between aLine and bLine.
Use the count to iterate the SEARCH for a match in ALL rows between aLine and bLine.
Determine if there is a better way to handle reading the data file vs. opening in each function.

Comment: Do you want to output a dataframe or just iterate over each 'SET'?

Comment: The path of least resistance.   The end goal is just to be able to count the calls and understand the call volume over time.

Comment: If that is your goal I would suggest change the problem description and provide a sample of the final output (i.e. a summary of call volume).

Comment: It seems that some users have time-overlapped START ... STOP sequences (e.g. xxxx726). It would be tricky to handle SEARCH actions in those overlapped time periods.

Comment: Agreed.  There are 3 multi-conditional searches needed.  If I could increment N by 1 on each loop, then 1. Find START where INDEX = N (Assign LOGIN to VarL, TIME to VarT1). 2 Find STOP where INDEX = N.(Assign TIME to VarT2)  3. Find SEARCH by LOGIN VarL between VarT1 and VarT2.

Comment: There is no information in a SEARCH row to associate it with a particular START ... STOP sequence. So in that special case you might just choose one arbitrarily or use some heuristics to decide.

Comment: You still need to deal with SEARCH actions that can be associated with multiple START ... STOP sequences in your approach. A slightly different approach is to start with each SEARCH action and find its associated START ... STOP sequence.

Comment: so each call has a unique ID in the INDEX column. From the SET example above, TIME:3/10/2019 14:53 INDEX:1853 TYPE:START LOGIN:xxxx732
TIME:3/10/2019 15:11 INDEX:1853 TYPE:STOP LOGIN:xxxx732

Comment: There are no IDs provided for the SEARCH actions.

Comment: I have had some success using the csv library. I have updated the question, illustrating the current state of affairs under an **UPDATE** section.   I am working on the outstanding goals now.  Does it make sense to delete this post and resubmit the problem without a pandas flag, illustrating the notes from the **UPDATE** section?

Answer (score 0):

To count the number of calls, you can mesure the length of a `groupby` on the INDEX column:

```
mask_search = df['TYPE']=='SEARCH'
df_no_search = df.drop(df[mask_search].index)

# Number of calls 
print(len(df_no_search .groupby(['INDEX']).size())-1)

# To count the number of unique calls each day : 
df.drop(df[mask_search].index).groupby(['DATE'])['INDEX'].nunique()
```

To get the details of each call, you can do several groupby's :

```
df.groupby(['LOGIN', 'TIME','INDEX', 'TYPE' ]).size()
```

Output :

```
LOGIN    TIME             INDEX  TYPE  
xxxx619  3/10/2019 15:05  1854   START     1
         3/10/2019 15:07  1851   STOP      1
         3/10/2019 15:09  1858   START     1
xxxx726  3/10/2019 14:55  1850   START     1
         3/10/2019 14:59  1852   START     1
         3/10/2019 15:05  1850   STOP      1
         3/10/2019 15:08  1852   STOP      1
         3/10/2019 15:09  1860   START     1
xxxx732  3/10/2019 14:53  1853   START     1
         3/10/2019 14:57  0      SEARCH    1
         3/10/2019 15:04  0      SEARCH    1
         3/10/2019 15:09  1856   START     1
         3/10/2019 15:11  1853   STOP      1
xxxx738  3/10/2019 14:54  1848   START     1
         3/10/2019 14:57  1855   START     1
         3/10/2019 15:00  1848   STOP      1
xxxx744  3/10/2019 14:55  1846   STOP      1
         3/10/2019 14:56  1849   START     1
         3/10/2019 15:00  1847   STOP      1
         3/10/2019 15:03  1849   STOP      1
```

---

Comment: The problem statement does not explain how the volume needs to be calculated so I demand the poster to clarify that. It is possible that he wants to calculate the number of active calls every minute. In that case the solution would be completely different.

Comment: You're right his question could be clearer. That's why I tried to offer several pieces of answers to his question. Because he doesn't seem to know exactly what he wants. Hopefully this answer will be what he wants, otherwise it will at least help him to clarify his question ( and I'll delete my answer if it becomes obsolete)

Comment: Thank you for your quick response!  I apologize for not being very clear. I have edited the original question, adding detail regarding the output.